# React router 'to' through props in const

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I suspect this is more about React (or JS) than routing.

To avoid props collision, I am using forwardRef, defined in a const. The 'to' I want to set through props passed from parent component, and I cannot get this work. In the example below, where it says `to={props.toUrl}` it only works if it is `to='/hello'`. How do I do this, so I can use the ButtonRouter component from the Demo component?

```
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const CollisionLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Link innerRef={ref} to={props.toUrl} {...props} />
));

function ButtonRouter(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Button component={CollisionLink}>Routing w/o props collision</Button>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default function Demo() {
  return <ButtonRouter toUrl="/hello" />;
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any props to `CollisionLink` from `ButtonRouter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing props from `ButtonRouter`:

```
function ButtonRouter(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Button component={(routerProps) => <CollisionLink {...routerProps} {...props} />}>Routing w/o props collision</Button>
    </Router>
  );
}
```